# Create Django Table displaying information about users

Tags: django

I am currently using django 1.8 and I'd like to create a more intelligent way to display information about users.  Say I have something like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Invitation(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to create a field that is the unique number of user's an inviter has invited.  I could see how this could be done with something like `set("SELECT invitee FROM INVITATIONS WHERE inviter = 'my-user';")`, but if I want this displayed in the admin panel, is there a simple way to present this?

Also, I would want this done for every user, so it feels like there is a simple way to make a field generated for every user in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's setup proper `related_name`- it'll help reduce a lot of confusion in the code.

```
class Invitation(models.Model):

    inviter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitation_sent")
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitation_recv")
```

With the `related_name` setup, we can do queries such as

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

# retrieve all invitation objects sent by this user
user.invitation_sent.all() 

# retrieve all invitation objects received by this user
user.invitation_recv.all()
```

Now we can actually count the number of unique invitations a user has sent out quite easily:

```
# count number of distinct invitee for user
user.invitation_sent.all().values('invitee').distinct().count()
```

Next, we can actually count the number of unique users a user has invited in a single database query for *all* users:

```
user_list = User.objects.all().annotate(
    uniq_inv=Count('invitation_sent__invitee', distinct=True)
)
```

Each user object returned will have an additional property called `uniq_inv` which contains the count of unique users the user has invited

```
for user in user_list:
    print(user.name + ' invited ' + user.uniq_inv + ' unique users')
```

To apply this to the admin interface, you'll need to override `get_queryset` method:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = [..., 'uniq_inv']

    def uniq_inv(self, obj):
        return obj.uniq_inv
    uniq_inv.short_description = 'Unique Invitees'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(uniq_inv=Count('invitation_sent__invitee', distinct=True))
        return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotate, which allows to add calculated fields to a queryset.

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Invitation(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="inviter_user")
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="invited_user")
```

Queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count
q = Invitation.objects.annotate(count_invitee=Count('invitee')).all()
```

Now "count_invitee" field has the number for each invitation object.

If you want to filter invitee from the user side.
For a single user:

```
User.objects.get(pk=1).invited_user.all.count()
```

For all users queryset:

```
User.objects.annotate((count_invitee=Count('invited_user')).all()
```

Comment: I meant the number of user's a User has invited.  So it would be the set of all invitee's where the user was the inviter

Comment: will it run this every time?  I feel like this may start to get very computationally expensive as the database grows.

Comment: this answer is wrong- the annotation will return the number of invitations the user has received, not the number of unique invitees for the user. Even if the annotation were switched to count `inviter_user` (which is what Rob is looking for) - it still wouldn't count the number of unique user invited.